# Parse number in BBCode

Tags: php, regex, bbcode

I have a BBCode quote tag that is formatted like this:

```
[quote=Username;123456]
```

The delimiter is always there. How can I only match the digits with a regular expression (PHP)?

Comment: First of all, please use modern solutions for BBCode, I recommend my own library https://github.com/thunderer/Shortcode . You'll get the whole BBCode value which you can then explode as you wish. Happy to answer any questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way (among others):

```
\[[^\d\[\]]+(\d+)\]
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/lE5qL2/1).

---

Broken down, this says:

```
\[         # match an open bracket
[^\d\[\]]+ # match anything not brackets or digits
(\d+)      # capture digits to group $1
\]         # match a closing bracket
```

Your digits will be in group `$1`.

Comment: Or [`explode(";", trim("[quote=Username;123456]", "[]"))[1];`](http://ideone.com/AM2SAY)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Of course. I'd go another way as well but OP asked for regex.